# Small image overlay on div hover (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a jQuery image overlay on div hover function, but I'm stuck on some weird behavior. Hopefully someone can help me get the bugs out of this thing (inspired by [jQuery image hover color overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030988/jquery-image-hover-color-overlay))

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>Test page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.tile').bind('mouseover', function () {
                $(this).css({ position: 'relative' });
                $('<div />').text(' ').css({
                    'height': $(this).height(),
                    'width': $(this).width(),
                    'background': 'url(hover_top.png) top left no-repeat',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'top': 0,
                    'left': 0,
                    'opacity': 0.0
                }).addClass("hover-tile").bind('mouseout', function () {
                    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                        $(".hover-tile").each(function () { $(this).remove(); });
                    });
                }).appendTo(this).animate({
                    'opacity': 0.5
                }, 'fast');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { background: #ddd; }
        .left { float: left; }
        .tile { width: 200px; height: 65px; background-color: Red; cursor: pointer; margin: 10px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="tile left">
            <div class="title">This is title 1</div>
            <div class="description">This is description 1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="tile left">
            <div class="title">This is title 2</div>
            <div class="description"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="tile left">
            <div class="title">This is title 3</div>
            <div class="description">This is description 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

hover_top.png is just a small 10x10 pixel image that I want displayed on top of the tile div (top-left corner). The image is displayed on hover, but disappears quickly (because of lost focus, I assume).

Hopefully someone can help me work out the quirks! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouseenter and mouseleave unless you have a specific need for mouseover. There's an example of the difference in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/).