# Trying to build Home page for a website that contains a clickable image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to make the image clickable and on hover I want to change the background image

```
<style media="all" type=text/css> 
  body {   
    background: url(http://www.acrosszero.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-picture_screen.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;   
    -webkit-background-size: cover;   
    -moz-background-size: cover;  
    -o-background-size: cover;  
    background-size: cover;   
    position: relative; 
  }  
 </style>
```

Comment: Right now `http://www.acrosszero.org/` is clickable and hoverable

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery image hover color overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030988/jquery-image-hover-color-overlay)

Comment: Just to clarify. You want the background image of the body to change? And when you hover over what?

Comment: Hi ...Please refer to my below comment in which I explained what exactly I am trying to achieve. Thank you for all the help :D

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, you need the following HTML and CSS code.

HTML

```
<body>
    <a href="#" class="bg-image"></a>
</body>
```

The anchor-tag `a` makes sure you can click on it and use it as a link.

CSS

```
<style media="all" type=text/css>
* {
    // this resets the padding and margins in all browsers in order to keep the image on the full screen. 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.bg-image {
    background: url(http://www.acrosszero.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-picture_screen.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.bg-image:hover {
    background: url(the_hover_image.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
}
</style>
```

Maybe you will need to reset the anchor-tag styling.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply...:D   The only problem is the image is getting distorted and is not appearing on the complete browser window. Just to make it clear what I am trying to achieve is to have a Home page with only an image in which a specific part (in my case XO changes colour on hovering) [that is why I chose to change the image on hovering so that it appears to the user that the XO is getting colored] That way the user will know that the image is clickable and on clicking I wish the main page with menu to appear

Comment: This is because you use "background-size: cover". On CSS Tricks they offer you different solutions. I would advise to go with the jQuery version. Here is the link https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you want the background image to change when you hover over the body and to turn the whole `<body>` element into a hyperlink? This should work:

HTML:

```
<body onClick="location.href='URL'"></body> <!-- Makes it clickable -->
```

CSS:

```
body {
 cursor: pointer; /*Makes the cursor appear as it would when hovering over a link*/
}

body:hover {
 background-image: url('image.png'); /*Makes the image change when hovering*/
}
```

Comment: Hi I kind of tried combining the two codes mentioned here and it worked well , now the image is not getting distorted...but unfortunately the hover function is not working :/

Comment: <body
    onClick="location.href='http://www.acrosszero.org/?page_id=71'" >
</body>
<style media="all" type=text/css>
body {
 cursor: pointer; 
  background: url(http://www.acrosszero.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-picture_screen.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body:hover {
 background-image: url(http://www.acrosszero.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/xo-with-colrd.jpg); 
}
</style>

Comment: When I go to http://www.acrosszero.org/ it works fine now. Have you changed something since your comment?